# How to put lists below each other? Python 3.6

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list Tmp in Python, looks like below:

```
      A1      A2        B1        B2        C1         C2  
0    17.387  17.470     19.93     13.29     19.93     19.93  
1    17.680  17.896     21.85     14.57     21.86     21.86  
2    17.787  17.228     24.46     16.30     24.45     24.45
```

I used this code to select different columns:

```
cols1 = [col for col in cols if '1' in col]
combined1 = combined[cols1]

cols2 = [col for col in cols if '2' in col]
combined21 = combined[cols2]
```

I want to make a list looks like:

```
        A1      A2                         
0     17.387  17.470         
1     17.680  17.896         
2     17.787  17.228      
3       B1      B2   #I also want to delet the titles in between
4     19.93   13.29 
5     21.85   14.57
6     24.46   16.30   
7       C1      C2 
8     19.93   19.93 
9     21.86   21.86  
10    24.45   24.45
```

I tried `pd.concat`, `append`, both of them seem not working. 
Do you have any solutions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to lose the 'A' 'B' and 'C' entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the two sub DataFrames (for the 1 index and the 2 index) with a [boolean mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). [`Unstacking`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) will turn each of those into a series. Then you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) those Series to get your result.

```
m1 = df.columns.str.endswith('1')
df1 = df.loc[:, m1].unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.loc[:, ~m1].unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

returns

```
        0       1
0  17.387  17.470
1  17.680  17.896
2  17.787  17.228
3  19.930  13.290
4  21.850  14.570
5  24.460  16.300
6  19.930  19.930
7  21.860  21.860
8  24.450  24.450
```

Comment: Very nice solution !

Comment: It indeed helps!

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way:

```
In [32]: pd.concat([df[g].rename(columns=lambda c:'A'+c[-1])
    ...:            for g in df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).groups.values()],
    ...:           ignore_index=True)
    ...:
Out[32]:
       A1      A2
0  17.387  17.470
1  17.680  17.896
2  17.787  17.228
3  19.930  13.290
4  21.850  14.570
5  24.460  16.300
6  19.930  19.930
7  21.860  21.860
8  24.450  24.450
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do using Pandas reshaping:

```
d1 = df.T
g = d1.index.str[0]
df_out = d1.set_index([g,d1.groupby(g).cumcount()])\
           .stack().unstack(1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
        0       1
0  17.387  17.470
1  17.680  17.896
2  17.787  17.228
3  19.930  13.290
4  21.850  14.570
5  24.460  16.300
6  19.930  19.930
7  21.860  21.860
8  24.450  24.450
```